# Communication channel error when running BigQuery udf

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I recently posted on stack overflow about an OOM error while running many udfs on a single table ([bigquery udf out of memory issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414883/bigquery-udf-out-of-memory-issues)).  This error seems to have been partially fixed, however, I am running into a new error when running a udf on a 10,000 row table.  Here is the error message:

**Error**: An error occurred while communicating with a subprocess. message: "Communication channel error during 4 command" sandbox_process_error { }

**Error Location**: User-defined function

**Job ID**: broad-cga-het:bquijob_32bc01d_1569f11b8a2

The error does not occur when I remove the emit statement in the udf, so the error must be occurring when the udf tries to write back to a different table.

Here is a copy of the udf itself:

```
bigquery.defineFunction(
  'permute',
  ['obj_nums','num_obj_per_indiv','row_number'], // Names of input columns
  [{"name": "num_cooccurrences_list","type": "string","mode":"nullable"}], // Output schema
  permute
);

function permute(row, emit) {

  var obj_ids = row['obj_nums'].split(",").map(function (x) { 
      return parseInt(x, 10); 
  });

  var num_obj_per_indiv = row['num_obj_per_indiv'].split(",").map(function (x) { 
      return parseInt(x, 10); 
  });

  var row_number = row['row_number']

  // randomly shuffle objs using Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm
  obj_ids = shuffle_objs(obj_ids);
  // form dictionary of obj_pairs from obj_ids
  var perm_run_obj_set = new Set(obj_ids);
  var perm_run_obj_unique = Array.from(perm_run_obj_set);
  perm_run_obj_unique.sort();
  var perm_run_obj_pairs_dict = {};
  output = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < perm_run_obj_unique.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < perm_run_obj_unique.length; j++) {
      var obj_pair = [perm_run_obj_unique[i],perm_run_obj_unique[j]].sort().join("_")
      perm_run_obj_pairs_dict[obj_pair] = 0
    }
  }

  // use fixed number of objs per indiv and draw from shuffled objs
  var perm_cooccur_dict = {};

        //num_obj_per_indiv = num_obj_per_indiv.slice(0,3);

        for(var index in num_obj_per_indiv) {

                var obj_count = num_obj_per_indiv[index]
                var perm_run_objs = [];
                for(var j = 0; j < obj_count; j++) {
                        perm_run_objs.push(obj_ids.pop());
                }

                perm_run_objs = new Set(perm_run_objs);
                perm_run_objs = Array.from(perm_run_objs)
                while(perm_run_objs.length > 1) {

                         current_obj = perm_run_objs.pop()
                         for(var pair_obj_ind in perm_run_objs) {
                                  var pair_obj = perm_run_objs[pair_obj_ind]
                                  var sorted_pair = [current_obj,pair_obj].sort().join("_")
                                  perm_run_obj_pairs_dict[sorted_pair] += 1
                                  // console.log({"obj_pair":[current_obj,pair_obj].sort().join("_"),"perm_run_id":row_number})
                                  // emit({"obj_pair":[current_obj,pair_obj].sort().join("_"),"perm_run_id":row_number});
                          }
                 }
        }
        // emit({"obj_pair":[current_obj,pair_obj].sort().join("_"),"perm_run_id":row_number});
  // form output dictionary
  num_cooccur_output = ""
  for (var obj_pair in perm_run_obj_pairs_dict) {
    //emit({"obj_pair":obj_pair,"num_cooccur":perm_run_obj_pairs_dict[obj_pair]});
      num_cooccur_output += String(perm_run_obj_pairs_dict[obj_pair])
      num_cooccur_output += ","
  }
  num_cooccur_output = num_cooccur_output.substring(0, num_cooccur_output.length - 1);
  emit({"num_cooccurrences_list":num_cooccur_output});
}

/**
 * Randomize array element order in-place.
 * Using Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm.
 */
function shuffle_objs(obj_array) {
  for (var i = obj_array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = obj_array[i];
    obj_array[i] = obj_array[j];
    obj_array[j] = temp;
  }
        return obj_array;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: Hi, any update on this issue? We are experiencing the same; moreover, retries don't help. We are running a bunch of similar jobs and half of them failes. These are always the same jobs and as a result, the whole task is currently blocked. Started maybe a week ago without any changes in our code. (for example, job_8eQwaFaMZyYp6B7lIifBBAOijnQ).

Answer (score 0):

Not that this directly answers your original question, but I'm not convinced that you need a UDF for this type of transformation. For example, using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options") you can perform an array transformation such as:

```
WITH T AS (SELECT [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] AS arr)
SELECT
  x,
  new_x
FROM T,
  UNNEST(
    ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT
            x,
            arr[OFFSET(CAST(RAND() * (off + 1) AS INT64))] AS new_x
          FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x WITH OFFSET off));
+---+-------+
| x | new_x |
+---+-------+
| 0 | 1     |
| 1 | 2     |
| 2 | 0     |
| 3 | 2     |
| 4 | 4     |
| 5 | 0     |
| 6 | 5     |
| 7 | 4     |
| 8 | 8     |
| 9 | 3     |
+---+-------+
```

I can explain more if it helps, but the gist of the query is that it randomizes the elements in `arr` using the formula from your UDF above. The `FROM T, UNNEST(...` unrolls the elements of the array to make them easier to see, but I could have alternatively done:

```
WITH T AS (SELECT [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] AS arr)
SELECT
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT
          x,
          arr[OFFSET(CAST(RAND() * (off + 1) AS INT64))] AS new_x
        FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x WITH OFFSET off)
FROM T;
```

This gives an array of structs as output, where each `x` is associated with `new_x`.

Comment: Hi Elliot, This is a great suggestion, and I was planning to do exactly that, to do the same operation in a query instead of a udf.  Thank you for helping me get started with that :)

I do think this problem still highlights a limitation of the BigQuery udf functionality, and it would be great if there is a possible fix for the udf as well, but for the meantime I am happy to write a query to do essentially the same thing as the udf.